# Retrieving maximum date from SpatiaLite DB in QGIS as a filter

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite

I have a SpatiaLite DB layer with geometry that displays correctly and has lots of associated attributes. The layer feature count is 40943.
One of these attributes is a "Date", and I would like to have two different symbols:
Latest date
Other (or not latest date or less than latest date)

Here is my filter showing, with "Test", that it's working, ie 4002/40943 features.
[image: Date = Maximum filter]

Here is the "Date" < maximum("Date") filter with "Test" showing 36941/40943 count:

[image: Date < Maximum filter]

Hit apply etc.
Now in the display I've only got Purple dots and no Big Red dots.
If I right-click either symbol layer in the "Layers" panel and try to select features "No matching features found"

Is there issues with filtering a Database layer?

The Date layer I believe is a type = Date
[image: Date type]

I've tried Categorized with many different iterations of maximum date, perhaps not the right one though! [image: failed attempts]

I've also tried saving it as a shapefile which converts "Date" type to "abc" string and that won't suit my purposes.

---

Using @RainForest VirtualField answer means I found my data it was a zone off. Once I located the data I retested my initial filter and it DOES WORK, BUT using the VirtualField as above allows feature selection whereas mine still reports "No matching features found". I guess it's just a small bug.

Comment: to check the formatting of your expression, can you try and run your expression outside of the Symbology GUI and maybe just try running it in a normal filter? (Right click on Layer > Filter ) - This will ensure that the single expressions are working on their own, and rendering of those expressions works stand-alone, which will help eliminate the potential problem.

Comment: Thanks for the check. The expression didn't work in the Filter. I tried something simple on a integer attribute and it worked fine. So now I have the issue of something working in one filter and not another. Is this worth raising to the QGIS dev team?

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual field 'MaxDate' with expression = maximum("Date"). Change comparision whith this field in the rule - "Date" = "MaxDate"

Comment: Thanks. This is a good work around. Still odd issues regarding feature selection.